# Show link if session user matches certain criteria

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, session-variables, actionview

I'm trying to make a specific link in my application only visible to users who have the attribute `:department` equal to "Sales".

In other words, I've got a model *Users*, in which a user has a `password`, `username`, and `department`.  The session saves the `:user_id` once the user is logged in.

What I would like to do is when my view is rendered, depending on the `:department` of the logged in user, either display, or don't display a specific link.

Here's the code I've got in my view, but I'm struggling with how to take the session info and find the department of the user from it.

```
<% if Users.where(id: session[:user_id])[:department] == "Sales" %>
  <%= link_to 'New Request', new_request_path %>
  <% else nil %>
<% end %>
```

I know it's bad to do a query anywhere other than the controller or model, so if you have any advice on how to better structure this logic as well, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is:

```
<% user = User.find_by_id(session[:user_id]) %>
<% if user.present? && user[:department] == "Sales" %>
  <%= link_to 'New Request', new_request_path %>
<% end %>
```

Personally, I'd put this into a helper method to clean it up:

In app/helpers/users_helper.rb:

```
def user_in_sales?
  user = User.find_by_id(session[:user_id])

  user.present? && user[:department] == "Sales"
end
```

Then your view:

```
<% if user_in_sales? %>
  <%= link_to 'New Request', new_request_path %>
<% end %>
```

Personally, I'd strongly look into using something like [cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) to handle this situation.  I think you may find that you could use cancan as an effective authorization tool other places in your app, especially if you're doing logic like this elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

First, you're using an object oriented language. It would help you to quit getting hung up on implementation details (e.g. department == "Sales") and instead consider the intent or meaning you're trying to express and code to meet that. For example:

```
if current_user.works_in?(:jewelry)
  link_to 'Request Receipt', new_request_path
end
```

Your models should expose a public interface that allows other objects in your code (like your controller) to get the information they need (i.e. whether or not a user has an association with a department) without knowledge of or concern for the underlying data storage schema.

```
class User
  def works_in?(department_name)
    departments.pluck(:name).include?(department_name.to_s)
  end
end
```